# Seeking a geometric characterisation of a certain property of a circle, a tangent ellipse within it, and a point strictly within the ellipse.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, plane-geometry

Consider a circle $C$, an ellipse $E$ strictly within $C$ except for a tangent point $p$, and a point $b$ strictly within $E$. Consider a point $q$ on $E$, and a point $q'$ given by the intersection of the extension of $qb$ with $E$, such that both $q$ and $q'$ are distinct from $p$. Define the points $r$ and $r'$ as the intersection of $C$ with the extensions of $pq$ and $pq'$ respectively.

> We are interested in whether the point $j$, the intersection of the extension of $pb$ with $rr'$, lies inside the ellipse.

We can show ([algebraically using Mathematica page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycuSQ.jpg),[page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE2CW.jpg)) that the point $j$ is a property only of $C$, $E$, and $b$, independent of $q$, as illustrated in the figure:

[[image: illustration of the independence of <span class=]$j$ on $q$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTl7m.png)

> So we would like some way to characterize this property (whether $j$ is interior to $E$) of $C$, $E$, and $b$, geometrically without introducing $q$.

Comment: *"We can show algebraically that this is a property only of $C$, $E$, and $b$, independent of $q$."* Please include your proof. This will save people from duplicating your effort, and it may provide someone with an immediate insight into the solution you seek. Plus, it should give some indication of your skill level, which can help answerers tailor their responses without wasting time explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond that level.

Comment: The proof was done using Mathematica. There is not much to say about it. We know the equation of a circle and an ellipse, and the the slope of an ellipse (for imposing the tangent condition). The point q was defined by introducing a line through b with slope k. An expression for j was found, and it is independent of k. The expressions are very lengthy.

Comment: Your drawing suggests that given C, E and b there is a unique point j, independent of q but your statement only makes the much weaker claim that j ist either always outside or always inside E independent of q. Which one do you mean?

Comment: I meant the former. I will edit the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in the locus of point $b$ when $j$ is inside ellipse $E$, you could reverse your construction: take any point $j$ on $E$, trace from $j$ any line intersecting circle $C$ at $r$, $r'$ (that line is taken parallel to $x$ axis in figure below), join $pr$, $pr'$ to find their intersections $q$, $q'$ with $E$. Point $b$ lies on segment $qq'$. Repeating the construction for another line $tt'$ through $j$ you can find a second segment, whose intersection with $qq'$ is then point $b$ (otherwise, you could also find $b$ as the intersection of $pj$ and $qq'$).

I didn't embark into a computation, but with GeoGebra I could find the locus of $b$ as $j$ varies on the ellipse: it should be another ellipse (pink in figure below), tangent at $P$ with $C$ and having its axes parallel to those of $E$.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Consider an ellipse in standard position with equation
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1 \tag1$$
and define $c^2 := a^2 - b^2$. At point $T=(a\cos t,b\sin t)$, with $0\leq t\leq \pi$ (to avoid sign complications), the ellipse has unit *inward* normal $\vec{u}$ and unit *clockwise* tangent vector $\vec{v}$ given by
$$
\vec{u} := \frac1s\left(-b\cos t, -a \sin t\right) \quad 
\vec{v} := \frac1s\left(a\sin t, -b\cos t\right) \quad 
s := \sqrt{a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2t} \tag2$$
We can parameterize points on the ellipse thusly:
$$E(\theta) = T + \frac{2 a b s^3 \cos\theta }{\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
(c^2 (a^2 \sin^2\theta - b^2 \cos^2\theta)+a^2b^2) \cos^2\theta \\
+ a^2 b^2 \sin^2\theta 
+ a b c^2 \sin2t \cos\theta \sin\theta
\end{array}\right)}\left( \vec{u} \cos\theta +  \vec{v} \sin\theta \right)
 \tag3$$
where $\theta$ is the angle that $\overrightarrow{TE}$ makes with normal vector $\vec{u}$. (We've effectively converted to a $uv$-coordinate system centered at $T$.) Note that $|TE|$ is the big multiplied factor, which amounts to a "polar" representation of the ellipse in the new coordinate system; the rectangular representation in that system (with $u$ and $v$ giving distances in the $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ directions from $T$) can be read immediately from the coefficients of $\cos^2\theta$, $\sin^2\theta$, $\sin\theta\cos\theta$ in the denominator, and $\cos\theta$ (with a sign change) in the numerator:

$$\begin{align}
u^2 (c^2 (a^2 \sin^2t- b^2 \cos^2t)+a^2b^2) + v^2 a^2 b^2 + u v a b c^2 \sin2t - 2 u a b s^3 = 0 \tag4
\end{align}$$

From this we find that (ignoring special cases) the axes of the ellipse are rotated relative to the $uv$-frame by an angle $\phi$ satisfying
$$\tan2\phi = \frac{\text{coeff of}\; uv}{(\text{coeff of}\; u^2) - (\text{coeff of}\; v^2)} = \frac{a b\sin2t}{a^2\sin^2t-b^2\cos^2t} \tag5$$

---

Now, we'll get at OP's construction by considering points $P$ and $Q$ on the ellipse for angles $\theta=p$ and $\theta=q$, and taking $R$ to be the intersection of $\overline{PQ}$ with the line through $T$ making angle  $r$ with vector $u$. (This $R$ plays the role of OP's point $b$, with $P$ and $Q$ corresponding to $q$ and $q'$.) We find that
$$|TR| = \frac{2 a b s^3}{
\left(\begin{array}{c}
   (a^4\sin^2t + b^4 \cos^2t) \cos r + a b c^2 \sin2t \sin r \\
 + a^2 b^2 ((\tan p + \tan q) \sin r - \tan p \tan q \cos r)
\end{array}\right)  
} \tag6$$
We can manipulate this into
$$\begin{align}
\frac1{a^2b^2}&\left(
\frac{2 a b s^3}{|TR|} 
- (a^4 \sin^2t + b^4 \cos^2t) \cos r 
- a b c^2 \sin2t \sin r 
\right) \\[4pt]
&= (\tan p + \tan q ) \sin r - \tan p \tan q \cos r 
\end{align} \tag7$$

The significance of $(7)$ is that its right-hand side is devoid of ellipse-specific parameters, while its left-hand side is devoid of $P$- and $Q$-specific parameters.

To see why this is helpful, consider *another* ellipse (generalizing OP's circle) with parameters, say, $\hat{a}$, $\hat{b}$ (and $\hat{c}$), and a point $\hat{T}:=(\hat{a}\cos\hat{t}, \hat{b}\sin\hat{t})$ on it. We can parameterize *that* ellipse relative to unit normal and tangent vectors $\hat{u}$ and $\hat{v}$ (with $\hat{s}$) at $\hat{T}$. Let's move this new ellipse to be tangent to the first, aligning $\hat{T}$, $\hat{u}$, and $\hat{v}$ with with $T$, $\vec{u}$, and $\vec{v}$. Then we can use the lines through $T=\hat{T}$ with the earlier direction angles $p$, $q$, $r$ (no hats!) determine points $\hat{P}$ (collinear with $T$ and $P$), $\hat{Q}$ (likewise), $\hat{R}$ (likewise) on this new ellipse. The last of these points satisfies a suitably-hatted counterpart to $(6)$, and thus also a counterpart to $(7)$; since the right-hand sides of $(7)$ and this new relation match, their left-hand sides do, too. That is, we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac1{a^2b^2}&\left(
\frac{2 a b s^3}{|TR|} 
- (a^4 \sin^2t + b^4 \cos^2t) \cos r 
- a b c^2 \sin2t \sin r 
\right) \\[4pt]
= \frac1{\hat{a}^2\hat{b}^2}&\left(
\frac{2 \hat{a} \hat{b} \hat{s}^3}{|T\hat{R}|} 
- (\hat{a}^4 \sin^2\hat{t} + \hat{b}^4 \cos^2\hat{t}) \cos r 
- \hat{a} \hat{b} \hat{c}^2 \sin2\hat{t} \sin r 
\right)
\end{align} \tag8$$
In this way, we have confirmed OP's assertion (generalized to not-necessarily-circular ellipses) that the relative positions of $R$ and $\hat{R}$ along the $r$-line are independent of the points along the $p$- and $q$-lines.

For the question-proper, we seek the locus of $R$ when $\hat{R}$ traces the $ab$-ellipse.

[image]

That is, when $\hat{R}=E(r)$, so that $|T\hat{R}|$ is the big factor in $(3)$, with $\theta=r$. Substituting this into $(6)$ and solving for $|TR|$ gives
$$\begin{align}
|TR| &= 
\frac{-D \cos r}{A \cos^2r + B \cos r\sin r + C \sin^2r} \\[8pt]
A &= 
  \hat{a}\hat{b} c^2 (a b \hat{s}^3 + \hat{a} \hat{b} s^3 ) (a^2 \sin^2t - b^2 \cos^2t) \\
&\phantom{=}- a^2 b^2 \hat{c}^2 s^3 (\hat{a}^2 \sin^2\hat{t} - \hat{b}^2 \cos^2\hat{t}) \\
&\phantom{=}+ a^3 b^3 \hat{a} \hat{b} \hat{s}^3 \\[4pt]
B &= a b \hat{a}\hat{b} (c^2 ( a b \hat{s}^3 + \hat{a} \hat{b} s^3) \sin2t - a b \hat{c}^2 s^3 \sin2\hat{t}) \\[4pt]
C &= a^3b^3 \hat{a}\hat{b}\hat{s}^3 \\[4pt]
D &= -2 a b s^6 \hat{a}^2 \hat{b}^2
\end{align}
\tag9$$

This is the "polar" representation (in our $uv$ coordinate frame) of *yet another* ellipse tangent at $T=T'$, as suggested by [Intelligenti pauca's sketch](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3903429/409). Its rectangular representation (with $u$ and $v$ representing the distances from $T$ in the $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ directions) is
$$A u^2 + B u v + C v^2 + D u + E v + F = 0 \quad (E=F=0)$$

---

Gleaning the exact geometry of this ellipse a bit of a chore in general. Let us simplify to OP's specific case, where the $\hat{a}\hat{b}$-ellipse is a circle; we have $\hat{a}=\hat{b}=\hat{s}$ and $\hat{c}=0$, so that

$$\begin{align}
A &= c^2 (a b \hat{a} + s^3 ) (a^2 \sin^2t - b^2 \cos^2t) + a^3 b^3 \hat{a} \\[4pt]
B &= a b c^2 ( a b \hat{a} + s^3) \sin2t \\[4pt]
C &= a^3b^3 \hat{a} \\[4pt]
D &= -2 a b s^6
\end{align}
\tag9$$

Then we readily find that this ellipse is rotated relative to the $uv$-frame by $\phi$ satisfying
$$\tan2\phi=\frac{B}{A-C} = \frac{ab\sin2t}{a^2\sin^2t-b^2\cos^2t} \tag{10}$$
which matches $(5)$, confirming [Intelligenti pauca](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3903429/409)'s suspicion that the axes of this ellipse are parallel to those of the $ab$-ellipse. The center of this  ellipse is
$$(u,v) = \frac{D}{B^2-4AC}(2C,-B) = \frac{s^2}{2mn} (2a^2 b^2 \hat{a}, -c^2 p\sin2t) \\[16pt]
m := a b \hat{a} - c^2 s \cos^2t \qquad 
n := a b \hat{a} + c^2 s \sin^2t \qquad
p := a b \hat{a} + s^3
\tag{11}$$

Rotating the ellipse by $\phi$ to align its axes with $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ gives

$$u^2 b^2 m
 + v^2 a^2  n
 + 2 u a b^2 s^3 \cos t
 + 2 v a^2 b s^3 \sin t = 0 \tag{12}$$

That is,
$$\left(u + \frac{a s^3 \cos t}{m}\right)^2 \frac{m^2 n}{a^3 b \hat{a} s^6}
 + \left(v + \frac{b s^3 \sin t}{n}\right)^2 \frac{mn^2}{a b^3 \hat{a} s^6}
 = 1 \tag{12'}$$
From this, we read that the major and minor radii (say, $a'$ and $b'$) of this third ellipse are
$$a' = \sqrt{\frac{a^3 b \hat{a} s^6}{m^2 n}} \qquad b' = \sqrt{\frac{a b^3 \hat{a} s^6}{mn^2}} \quad\to\quad (c')^2 := (a')^2-(b')^2 = \frac{a b c^2 \hat{a} p s^6}{m^2n^2} \tag{13}$$
and its eccentricity, $e'$, is
$$e' := \frac{c'}{a'} = \frac{c}{a}\; \sqrt{\frac{p}{n}} = e\;\sqrt{\frac{p}{n}} \tag{14}$$
where $e$ is the eccentricity of the $ab$-ellipse.

Determining other properties of these figures is left to the reader. $\square$